# Swift convert 'Character' to 'Unicode.Scalar'

Tags: swift, string, character, unicodescalar

I'm trying to filter non-alphabetical characters out of a String, but running into the issue that `CharacterSet` uses `Unicode.Scalar` and String consists of `Character`.

Xcode gives the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character') to specified type 'Unicode.Scalar?'

```
let name = "name"
let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.alphanumerics
let filteredName = name.filter { (c) -> Bool in
    if let s: Unicode.Scalar = c { // cannot convert
        return !allowedCharacters.contains(s)
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`CharacterSet` has an unfortunate name inherited from Objective C. In reality, it is a set of `Unicode.Scalar`s, not of `Characters` (“extended grapheme clusters” in Unicode parlance). This is necessary, because while there is a finite set of Unicode scalars, there is an infinite number of possible grapheme clusters. For example, `e + ◌̄ + ◌̄ + ◌̄ ...` *ad infinitum* is still just one cluster. As such, it is impossible to exhaustively list all possible clusters, and it is often impossible to list the subset of them that has a particular property. Set operations such as those in the question must use scalars instead (or at least use definitions derived from the component scalars).

In Swift, `String`s have a `unicodeScalars` property for operating on the string a the scalar level, and the property is directly mutable. That enables you to do things like this:

```swift
// Assuming...
var name: String = "..."

// ...then...
name.unicodeScalars.removeAll(where: { !CharacterSet.alphanumerics.contains($0) })
```

Answer (score 13):

A single `Character` can consist of several `UnicodeScalar`s, so you need to iterate through all of them and check if they are contained in `CharacterSet.alphanumerics`.

```
let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.alphanumerics
let filteredName = name.filter { (c) -> Bool in
    return !c.unicodeScalars.contains(where: { !allowedCharacters.contains($0)})
}
```

Test input: `let name = "asd1"`

Test output: `"asd1"`

Comment: @PeterLapisu in the modern world of Strings not just consisting of ASCII characters, handling `Unicode` characters correctly is a necessary evil

Comment: but it is ridiculous that a CharacterSet doesn't work with Character

Comment: @PeterLapisu that's because a `Character` can consist of several `UnicodeScalar`s (in case of complex emojis for instance). You could easily make this method an extension on `CharacterSet`.

Answer (score 2):

Without `var` or double-negatives:

```swift
let filteredName = String(name.unicodeScalars.filter {
    CharacterSet.alphanumerics.contains($0)
})
```